# Can we use enumerate with standalone class?

Tags: lists, standalone

Can we use `\enumerate` with `\standalone` class? Isn't `enumerate` basic LaTeX?
The minimal example, which does not compile with `standalone` but it does with `article`, is:

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
     \begin{document}
         \begin{enumerate}
             \item test 
          \end{enumerate}
      \end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently the `[varwidth]` option is the key.

```
 \documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
     \begin{document}
         \begin{enumerate}
             \item test 
          \end{enumerate}
      \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used this solution in answering the original version of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438554/. However, if the solution is applied to the code in the current version of the question, the resulting proof is incorrectly cropped. Do you by any chance know why this might be the case?

Comment: @cfr I am clueless as to the behavior.  I note in article class that it seems laterally offset as well.

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc uses `\item[$\square$]` and `\item[$\boxtimes$]` which just requires `amssymb` package:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth, crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % \square
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[$\square$] TODO
\item[$\boxtimes$] DONE
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]