# arev + textcomp: \textmu

Tags: sans-serif, textcomp

```
% varwidth --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178539 
\documentclass[border=2mm,varwidth]{standalone} 

% avec --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359530 
\usepackage{arev} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textcomp} % \textmu 
\usepackage{upgreek} % \upmu

\begin{document} 

\begin{itemize} 
\item \texttt{\textbackslash textmu:} \textmu 
\item \texttt{\$\textbackslash mu\$:}  $\mu$ 
\item \texttt{\$\textbackslash upmu\$:}  $\upmu$
\end{itemize} 

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

- I want to use the `arev` package (sans serif font).
- How do I get a sans serif `\textmu` (provided by the `textcomp` package)?
- Alternatively -- I just need an upright `\mu` when the main font is from the `arev` package.

---

### Solution

```
% varwidth --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178539 
\documentclass[border=2mm,varwidth]{standalone} 

% avec --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359530 
\usepackage{arev} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{myFontFamily}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{myFontFamily}{m}{n}{
   <-> favr8r
}{}
\newcommand{\myupmu}{{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{myFontFamily}\selectfont\symbol{181}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textcomp} % \textmu 
\usepackage{upgreek} % \upmu

\begin{document} 

\begin{itemize} 
\item \texttt{\textbackslash textmu:} \textmu m
\item Ulrike Fischer: {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{myFontFamily}\selectfont\symbol{181}}m
\item Ulrike Fischer Command: \myupmu m
\item \texttt{\$\textbackslash mu\$:}  $\mu m$ 
\item \texttt{\$\textbackslash upmu\$:}  $\upmu$
\end{itemize} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this approach could work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for the suggestion! I still hope that there is another approach :).

Comment: I wrote an email to the **author** of the arev package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an upright mu in the font, but it seems not to have been encoded. You can access it like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{arev}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{arev}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{arev}{m}{n}{
   <-> favr8r
}{}



\begin{document}
textmu: {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{arev}\selectfont\symbol{181}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can this considered to be a bug which should be reported (by me)?

Comment: Could you propose a robust way to put this into a simple command? I will use it very often, in micro meter.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug more a missing feature that there is no TS1-encoded arev font (I don't know if it isn't there because the font hasn't enough glyph coverage for textcomp, or if the author forgot it.)  You could try to contact the author. You can easily define a \arevtextmu to call this symbol.

Comment: Thanks. I also tested T1 encoding (fontenc package), but no luck.

Comment: No T1 won't work, \textmu is in TS1 and why should LaTeX put it in both?

Comment: Apparently I know nothing about encoding. Forget my comment :).