# how to display very large tree (+ standalone vs. bussproofs)

Tags: bussproofs

I am looking at different options to typeset proof trees, and be helped by [What is the best package out there to typeset proof trees?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468/what-is-the-best-package-out-there-to-typeset-proof-trees)

A question I don't see any hint therein is about whether there are tools to display very large proof trees (hundreds of nodes).  I am speculating/dreaming  about a tool to navigate a proof tree up and down (kind of what we do with google maps). Is there anything you may think of which could be suitable for doing that? How would you go to get something workable?

-------- second update

Thanks to **cfr**, I learnt about `varwidth` (without which it seems we get error messages: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{prooftree}`, why so?). Still, for a large number of proof steps, I get a cropped proof tree. I understand I may adjust the border's value, by trial and error. Question is: is there a way to ask latex to calculate the best value, for each given proof tree? Or at least, is there a way to know such value somehow in advance? (for the example below, `border=125pt` is good enough)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{A}
\UnaryInfC{B}
\AxiomC{C}
\BinaryInfC{D}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{J}
\AxiomC{A}
\UnaryInfC{B}
\AxiomC{C}
\BinaryInfC{D}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{J}
\BinaryInfC{JJ}
\AxiomC{A}
\UnaryInfC{B}
\AxiomC{C}
\BinaryInfC{D}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{J}
\AxiomC{A}
\UnaryInfC{B}
\AxiomC{C}
\BinaryInfC{D}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{J}
\BinaryInfC{JJ}
\BinaryInfC{JJJ}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `standalone` class and get a (very large) single page PDF. Navigation is then like any PDF, either scrolling or dragging.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with TeX? If so, see the LaTeX for Logicians site at `logicmatters`. If not, your question is off-topic. (Something google-map like is probably not best done with software designed for producing printed pages.)

Comment: @marmot Forest isn't great for this kind of proof tree.

Comment: @cfr I may agree with your () comment. Still, which software could transform a very large single .pdf (ps/dvi) page to something google-map like?

Comment: @ Torbjørn T.  I am looking at  `standalone`, it seems useful.  Do you happen to know about  a MWE, with some kind of large diagram/formula, and a large one page .pdf output?

Comment: @mario I don't know and this isn't the right place to ask.

Comment: What would be the point of having an MWE which met the description 'some kind of large diagram/formula'? Would that really be at all helpful. If so, take any MWE on the site based on `standalone` and make the font size something enormous, ensure you're using a scalable font and you've got the example you requested.

Comment: @cfr. Yes, I think I got the point. I checked with `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{fix-cm} \begin{document}
{\fontsize{999}{70}\selectfont See it huge AbC123}
\end{document}` I do get a large .pdf file. (instead .dvi seems to be cropped somehow).

Comment: You have an extra curly bracket: `\end{prooftree}}`.

Comment: I don't think you can use lists with the default configuration of `standalone`. At least, they've never worked for me. So, even fixing the extra bracket, you'll not make this work.

Comment: extra bracket is not the issue.

Comment: It certainly **was** the issue with the code you posted here. As I say, lists do not agree with `standalone`, at least in its default configuration. That's the issue with the **new** code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following  [Steven B. Segletes's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178541/), we can simply add `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{A}
    \UnaryInfC{B}
    \AxiomC{C}
    \BinaryInfC{D}
    \AxiomC{E}
    \AxiomC{F}
    \BinaryInfC{G}
    \UnaryInfC{H}
    \BinaryInfC{J}
  \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>bussproofs</code> <code>prooftree</code> in <code>standalone</code>]

Comment: @ cfr [border=10pt,varwidth] avoids error messages (fine! how so?). However, for a larger number of proof steps, I get a cropped proof tree. Please try with my new example. Let me know.

Comment: @mario I just followed the solution in the link. Maybe leave a comment asking there. The `border=10pt` is irrelevant: it was just to make it easier to take a screenshot of the tree bit and isn't part of the solution. Only the `varwidth` is doing anything.

Comment: For the cropping, i don't know enough about either `standalone` or `bussproofs`. Clearly, it loses track somehow, but I'm not sure of the how.

Comment: `border=10pt` is not irrilevant, since for `=125pt` the proof tree does not get cropped. Should I ask a separate question?

Comment: @mario It is irrelevant in the sense that it doesn't prevent the original error (`varwidth` does that) and it does not prevent cropping except by chance (i.e. you ask for a big enough border for your image to fit, even though it would otherwise get cropped). I think it would be good to ask a new question and to link to your question here: I have no idea how to answer the cropping part, but I'm not sure I should delete this since it does show how to prevent compilation failure with `standalone` and `bussproofs`. But if you'd rather I deleted this, I will. O/w I'd make your current question two.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439522/how-do-i-display-very-large-proof-trees-bussproofs-ebproofs-tikzs-tree-libra