# how do I display very large proof trees (bussproofs, ebproofs, tikz's tree library)

Tags: standalone, preview, logic, proof-package, bussproofs

I am looking at different options to typeset proof trees. I have asked a more [general question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438554/how-to-display-very-large-tree-standalone-vs-bussproofs)  and run into some issues. In particular I am trying to understand how to display very large proof trees, maybe with hundreds of nodes. I am trying different combinations of packages `bussproofs`, `ebproofs` or tikz's library `tree`,  and `standalone` or `preview`

In some cases the final proof tree is cropped, unless I set a large value for a border parameter. Issue (and question) is that I should not need to know such a value in advance. I do not understand why (it seems that) for some of those combinations I need to set it in advance.

Let me show my examples.

`bussproofs` + `standalone`. Output is cropped, unless I do not set a larger third (right) border parameter. If this could work, it would be the best settings for my little project. So the main question is: which piece of code I need to let pdf/latex to calculate the value  to display a given proof tree in a large enough .pdf (.ps, .dvi) file?

```
\documentclass[border={10pt 50pt 50pt 50pt},varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{A}
\UnaryInfC{B}
\AxiomC{C}
\BinaryInfC{D}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{J}
\AxiomC{A}
\UnaryInfC{B}
\AxiomC{C}
\BinaryInfC{D}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{J}
\BinaryInfC{JJ}
\AxiomC{A}
\UnaryInfC{B}
\AxiomC{C}
\BinaryInfC{D}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{J}
\AxiomC{A}
\UnaryInfC{B}
\AxiomC{C}
\BinaryInfC{D}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{J}
\BinaryInfC{JJ}
\BinaryInfC{JJJ}
% for a larger proof tree
% repeat all node as above, 
% and add a further line:  \BinaryInfC{JJJJ}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

`bussproofs` + `preview`. Output is cropped, unless I do not increase third (right) border parameter:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{prooftree}
\renewcommand\PreviewBbAdjust{-10pt -10pt 50pt 10pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
   AS ABOVE, CUT AND PASTE FROM ABOVE
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

`ebproofs` + `standalone`. Output is cropped, unless I do not increase third (right) border parameter from 10 to, say, 100:

```
\documentclass[border={10pt 10pt 10pt, 10pt},varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
      AS BELOW, CUT AND PASTE FROM BELOW
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

`ebproofs` + `preview`. **Output is fine!** This setting works. My question is: why so?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{prooftree}
\renewcommand\PreviewBbAdjust{-10pt -10pt 10pt 10pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
\infer1{ A &\vdash B, C }
\hypo{ D &\vdash E }
\infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\infer1{ A &\vdash B, C, D, E }
\hypo{ D &\vdash E }
\infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\hypo{ D &\vdash E  }
\infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\hypo{ D &\vdash E  }
\infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\hypo{ D &\vdash E  }
\infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\hypo{ D &\vdash E  }
\infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\hypo{ D &\vdash E  }
\infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\hypo{ D &\vdash E, 002 }
\infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E, 002 }
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

`tikz` + `preview`. Output is fine!, but I do not know whether there is a way to use tikz's tree library to define proof tree as in `bussproofs`/`ebproofs` (I suspect it is possible but it would need quite some work to be done)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {root}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child {node {left}}
    child {node {right}
        child[child anchor=north east] {node {AAA}}
        child {node {BBB}}
        [edge from parent fork down]
        child {node {BB0}}
        child {node {BB1}}
        [edge from parent fork down]
        child {node {BB0}}
        child {node {BB2}}
        [edge from parent fork down]
        child {node {BB0}}
        child {node {BB3}}
        %%%     REPEAT SEVERAL TIMES
        %%% [edge from parent fork down]
        %%%   child {node {BB0}}
        %%%   child {node {BBN}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---- EDIT

I got a comment from Emmanuel Beffara, who programmed `ebproofs`. I paste here with his permission.

> > >
> >     [...]  Regarding the fact that bussproofs+preview fails, apparently that is
> >     because the prooftree environment in bussproofs produces its result in
> >     vertical mode with the current page width, so bounding box calculation
> >     fails. You can pacth your example as follows:

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \usepackage{bussproofs}
  \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
  \newenvironment{hproof}{}{\DisplayProof} % Just so we have an environment
  \PreviewEnvironment{hproof}
  \renewcommand\PreviewBbAdjust{-10pt -10pt 10pt 10pt}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{hproof}
    % Same contents as before
  \end{hproof}
  \end{document}
```

> > > and it does work.
> > >
> > > As to how to use TikZ trees to render proofs, I don't know if it
> > >       practically feasible without much coding. At first I wanted to use TikZ
> > >       to develop ebproof, because it would allow drawing over proofs and
> > >       also rendering in very different styles, but I never found how to do the
> > >       required placement operations within TikZ, in particular using a
> > >       stack-based syntax, which is the only practical way of specifying
> > >       complex proofs as far as I can tell.

Comment: It would be much more awkward to use Ti*k*Z's `tree` library here, even if it can be done. This certainly wouldn't be a convenient solution, especially if you need to draw a number of proofs like this. @marmot I assume the latter.

Comment: Is there a question here and, if so, what is it?

Comment: Passing `14pt` to `article` gets you 10pt, by the way.