# How to remove blank space in standalone with lualatex?

Tags: luatex, standalone, white-space

While writing an Amharic poem, I got the following

[image]

I don't want the extra space on the right. What can I do? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\babelprovide[import,
  onchar = fonts ids,
  hyphenrules = +, % Use empty patters
  ]{amharic}

\babelposthyphenation{amharic}{([ሀሁሂሃሄህሆለሉሊላሌልሎሏሐሑሒሓሔሕሖሗመሙሚማሜምሞሟሠሡሢሣሤሥሦሧረሩሪራሬርሮሯሰሱሲሳሴስሶሷሸሹሺሻሼሽሾሿቀቁቂቃቄቅቆቈቊቋቌቍበቡቢባቤብቦቧቨቩቪቫቬቭቮቯተቱቲታቴትቶቷቸቹቺቻቼችቾቿኀኁኂኃኄኅኆኈኊኋኌኍነኑኒናኔንኖኗኘኙኚኛኜኝኞኟአኡኢኣኤእኦኧከኩኪካኬክኮኰኲኳኴኵኸኹኺኻኼኽኾወዉዊዋዌውዎዐዑዒዓዔዕዖዘዙዚዛዜዝዞዟዠዡዢዣዤዥዦዧየዩዪያዬይዮደዱዲዳዴጼጽጾጿፀፁፂፃፄፅፆፈፉፊፋፌፍፎፏፐፑፒፓፔፕፖፗ])}{
 { no = {1}, post = {1} }
}

\babelfont[amharic]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{፡}{፡\hskip0pt plus 3pt\relax}
\newunicodechar{።}{።\hskip0pt plus 3pt\relax}

\begin{document}

 

\noindent ላባ ላረጉልን የመከራ ሸክሙን\newline
ቀልደው ላሳቁን፣ ተጫውተው ላከሙን\\
በቸከ ዘመን ላይ ሰጋ ለበስ ትንግርት ሁነው ላስደመሙን\\
ቺርስ!\\


(አዳምኤል) 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to look at the varwidth option for standalone (untested)

Comment: @daleif `varwidth` cures a multitude of sins...https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178539/can-we-use-enumerate-with-standalone-class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@daleif's suggestion to employ the `varwidth` option of the `standalone` document class works. :-) I would, in addition, employ the option `border=1pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,
  onchar = fonts ids,
  hyphenrules = +, % Use empty patters
  ]{amharic}
\babelposthyphenation{amharic}{([ሀሁሂሃሄህሆለሉሊላሌልሎሏሐሑሒሓሔሕሖሗመሙሚማሜምሞሟሠሡሢሣሤሥሦሧረሩሪራሬርሮሯሰሱሲሳሴስሶሷሸሹሺሻሼሽሾሿቀቁቂቃቄቅቆቈቊቋቌቍበቡቢባቤብቦቧቨቩቪቫቬቭቮቯተቱቲታቴትቶቷቸቹቺቻቼችቾቿኀኁኂኃኄኅኆኈኊኋኌኍነኑኒናኔንኖኗኘኙኚኛኜኝኞኟአኡኢኣኤእኦኧከኩኪካኬክኮኰኲኳኴኵኸኹኺኻኼኽኾወዉዊዋዌውዎዐዑዒዓዔዕዖዘዙዚዛዜዝዞዟዠዡዢዣዤዥዦዧየዩዪያዬይዮደዱዲዳዴጼጽጾጿፀፁፂፃፄፅፆፈፉፊፋፌፍፎፏፐፑፒፓፔፕፖፗ])}{
 { no = {1}, post = {1} }
}
\babelfont[amharic]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{፡}{፡\hskip0pt plus 3pt\relax}
\newunicodechar{።}{።\hskip0pt plus 3pt\relax}

\begin{document}

ላባ ላረጉልን የመከራ ሸክሙን\newline
ቀልደው ላሳቁን፣ ተጫውተው ላከሙን\newline
በቸከ ዘመን ላይ ሰጋ ለበስ ትንግርት ሁነው ላስደመሙን\newline
ቺርስ!

(አዳምኤል) 
\end{document}
```